# Do physicists subscribe to Occam's razor? If so, how do you define 'all things being equal'?

Tags: soft-question

The question here is the title:

> Do physicists subscribe to Occam's razor? If so, how do you define 'all things being equal'?

Comment: This is *primarily opinion-based*. Some will love Occam's razor, some will have other criteria to choose between theories all empirical facts being equal. There's no objective answer to be had here.

Comment: my actual question is what does 'all things being equal' mean in the given context...

Comment: That the theories predict the same results for the same experiments? I don't see any ambiguity here.

Comment: I think you may have out-IQ'd me :)  I think I might know what you're getting at but my brain won't materialize it for me :)

Comment: Suppose you want to conduct an experiment to find the influence of A on B. Now since it's a reasonable suspicion that C, D, E, F etc etc *may* also have an influence on A, the trick is to keep C, D, E, F etc as constant as possible and only vary B in a controllable fashion. That's one meaning of 'all *other* things being equal'. It doesn't have much to do with Occam's Razor, AFAIK...

Comment: So it really means, "as long as there isn't any knowledge of a factor that causes one of the possibilities to be more plausible" --> the simplest one tends (note it doesn't say is most probable) to be correct..

Comment: Don't conflate the two. What I describe is a way to run experiments in the 'best' way possible. Occam's razor refers to how the simplest explanation of an outcome is probably the most plausible one. As ACM points out, some physicists will call that 'reductionism'.

Comment: There are other experiment designs that do vary (controllably) more than one physical quantity (say A, C, D and F) to find the influence on B, without any covariance between A, C, D and F, see factorial experiment designs.

Comment: The classic example of the ambiguity of these kinds of consideration rising to the surface is quantum interpretations. You can find people to tell with rock hard certainty that obvious proposal A is more parsimonious than proposal B. And a group just as certain the other way round. For essentially any pair of proposed interpretations.

Comment: strict parsimony is relative to the theoretical context.

Comment: Dark matter: Our review suggests it's time to ditch it in favor of a new theory of gravity https://phys.org/news/2022-07-dark-ditch-favor-theory-gravity.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Occam's raizor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Occam%27s_razor):

> The principle can be interpreted as
>
> Among competing hypotheses, the one with the fewest assumptions should be selected.

In this format it is continually used in the formation of physics theories. The simplest and more parsimonious the better. This resume about covers it:

> In science, Occam's razor is used as a heuristic technique (discovery tool) to guide scientists in the development of theoretical models, rather than as an arbiter between published models. In the scientific method, Occam's razor is not considered an irrefutable principle of logic or a scientific result; the preference for simplicity in the scientific method is based on the falsifiability criterion. For each accepted explanation of a phenomenon, there may be an extremely large, perhaps even incomprehensible, number of possible and more complex alternatives, because one can always burden failing explanations with ad hoc hypothesis to prevent them from being falsified; therefore, simpler theories are preferable to more complex ones because they are more testable.

As  for "all things being equal", it is not in the wiki definition. In physics it would mean, when  all  data are modeled/predicted by the theoretical modeling in all proposed theories, choose the simplest theory with the fewer hypotheses.

Comment: Nice answer. But a little *critique* of OR wouldn't go amiss here.

Comment: I would argue that OR is most useful in the development of *embryonic* theories and that when *'problems with the theory'* develop, complexification is often needed.

Comment: @Gert well, then among complexified proposals the simplest should be chosen.

Comment: yes, I think that's correct. 'All things being equal' in my reading at least, refers to choosing experimental set ups that exclude uncontrolled influences by variables not actually under study.